# Sort post by last commented

Tags: comments, query

I tried this :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts(array('orderby_last_comment' => true)); ?>
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [WP_Comment_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query).

The query will be

```
    $comments_query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'number' => 5,
        'status' => 'approve'
    );
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query();
    $recent_comments = $comments_query->query($comments_query_args);
```

Comment: Ok, but I want that for all my home page, not only the first 5 posts

Comment: If you remove the number argument it should work. Fo more information you can check the link which I provide in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand a bit your question. This query will take the last comments

Comment: You have to create a custom query to be able to sort by the last commented post. You can check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698438/ordering-wordpress-posts-by-most-recent-comment